# Eclipse RCP key binding

Tags: eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

Is there any ways to disable the currently active context that is associated with a key binding.

```
<context
        id="com.context" name="%com.context.name">
</context>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a plugin you can use the `IContextService` to activate and deactivate contexts.

However you can only deactivate a context that you activated since you need access to the activation context which you get from during context activation.